# Cross Domain AJAX Post - WCF

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain, jsonp

I have the following web service created and using the latest version of jquery I need to post to the web service.

I can not figure this out.  I've read that JSONP won't work with a POST.  How do I get this to work?

I need to do a cross domain post using jQuery to WCF.

service.cs:

```
namespace AjaxPost
{
    [DataContractAttribute]
    public class Message
    {
      [DataMemberAttribute]
      public string success;

      public Message(string success)
        this.success = success;
    }


    [ServiceContract(Namespace="JsonpAjaxService")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class User
    {
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method="POST")]
        public Message CreateUser(string email, string username, string password, string phone, string image)
        {
           Message msg = new Message("true");
           return msg;
        }
    }
}
```

service.svc:

```
<%@ServiceHost 
  language="c#"
  Debug="true"
  Service="Microsoft.Samples.Jsonp.CustomerService"
  Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory" 
%>
```

Service Web.Config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE" />
      </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>

<system.serviceModel>        
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" httpHelpPageEnabled="True" />
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webScriptEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
        </webScriptEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

index.html

```
    wcfServiceUrl = "http://localhost:33695/Service.svc/CreateUser";

    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: true,
        url: wcfServiceUrl,
        data: "{}",
        type: "POST",
        jsonpCallback: "Message",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{ \"myusername\": \"mypassword\" }",
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            //error loading data
            alert("error");
        },
        success: function (menu) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using CORS (HTML 5  Solution)
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Implementing-CORS-support-c1f9cd4b

If anyone knows a working solution that does not use CORS (HTML 5) that would be awesome.  Correct me if i'm wrong but, CORS requires HTML 5 supported browsers and I prefer a solution that is not reliant on a HTML 5 browser.

Comment: FYI, Edge doesn't seem to currently support CORS either...unless I have something wrong with my implementation of this link, but it works in all other broswers.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this without CORS.
All I had to do was to allow the server to receive calls from anywhere. This was done with apache, but I see your webserver has something similar.
The problem I had, was that I needed to specify the allowed domain, * did not work. Also, it had to be specified with http://site.example

Answer (score 1):

you dont have much choice but to use a serverside app to connect your webservice if it lies on another server.or just use JSONP (get requests ) . there is no other work around. CORS doesnt work on older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Due to http standards, same-origin policy might be in affect.  Is the website you are requesting located under a different app, or port?

See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: As I mentioned, the web service and web application are on different hosts.  This is a cross domain post I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Then you'd need a SOAP request or something of the like.  You can issue an ajax request to a method within the context of the web application trying to reach the web service, then have the application issue the SOAP request.

Comment: What ever I try to use I have issues.  I've tried every answer I found on the web.  I just got CORS to work with WCF. I was hoping to not have to use CORS as it is only supported by the newer browsers running html 5.  A solution that does not run CORS would be good to see.  A simple example of a jquery post to WCF would be nice.  I'll post my CORS example as the answer, and I'll change my answer if any one can post a working example that does not use CORS.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution that works. To solve the problem do the following:

Create a Global.asax and following code to enable Ajax cross-domain POST

```
 public void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST,OPTIONS");

            if ((HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS"))
            {

                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```